# Style wp_link_pages as a select drop down list

Tags: menus, pagination, navigation

I'm using `<?php wp_link_pages('next_or_number=number'); ?>` to display the pagination links for content that is split into multiple pages but I want to display the pagination links as a drop down select box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to achieve that is by constructing the `<option>` tags with the `wp_link_pages_link` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', function( $link, $i )
{
    return sprintf( 
        '<option value="%d" %s>%d</option>', 
        $i, 
        selected( $i, get_query_var( 'page', 1 ), 0 ), 
        $i 
    );
}, 10, 2 );
```

and then the `<form>` and `<select>` tags with the `wp_link_pages` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', function( $links )
{
    if( empty( $links ) )
        return $links;

    return sprintf( 
        '<form method="GET" action="">
            <select name="page">%s</select>
            <input type="submit" value="%s"/>
        </form>', 
        $links,
        esc_html__( 'Go to page', 'mydomain' )
    );
} );
```

Here's how it looks like in the *Twenty Sixteen* theme:

[image: example]

Hope you can adjust it to your needs!

Comment: I don't want a go to page button but instead go straight to the page once I select a page number. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add all new information into the question. That seems like a pure javascript problem now. You could search how to hook into the `onchange` event for a `select` tag, e.g. on StackOverflow @Ruriko